# cumulative distribution function for non-normal distribution

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, nonlinear, weibull-distribution, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

From this [article](https://www.isixsigma.com/tools-templates/normality/tips-recognizing-and-transforming-non-normal-data/), I read that the author drew four versions of CDFs each plotted in different distributions (all four plots come from the same sample data)

[image]

From these four plots, the author chooses specifically the Weibull distribution because the sample data is best represented in Weibull distribution. And he draws the following conclusion:

"A similar assessment can be made with a probability plot, which shows this is a predictable process and that 91 percent of the ER waiting times are within four hours."

[image]

Why did he specifically choose Weibull distribution to draw that conclusion? Couldn't you just use the CDF plotted in lognormal, exponential, or normal scale to draw the same conclusion?

My understanding of interpreting CDF says that reading percentiles should not be affected by different distribution scales.

Comment: I am assuming he chose Weibull because it has a non-significant and highest p-value of them all, based on a goodness of fit test.

Comment: @user2974951 Yes, but how does it affect reading the percentiles? Does the inverse of percentiles yield different values for different distributions?

Comment: Could it be based on the Anderson-Darling statistic value? Lower the AD value, better the fit.

Comment: If you look closely at the large plot, you will notice that the calculation uses the *fitted* line rather than the data points.  It should be clear that the lines in the small plots fit the data points rather differently, implying the answer depends on which plot is used.

Comment: Hi! Does anyone know how I can draw a graph like that?